# Find mongo records with duplicated values in array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider this mongo collection:

```
[{
        "_id": {
            "s": "HU",
            "k": 1
        },
        "boxed": {
            "values": [{
                    "s": "NL",
                    "k": 2
                },
                {
                    "s": "BR",
                    "k": 3
                },
                {
                    "s": "NL",
                    "k": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "s": "FR",
            "k": 2
        },
        "boxed": {
            "values": [{
                "s": "SE",
                "k": 99
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "s": "UA",
            "k": 14
        },
        "boxed": {}
    }
]
```

I'm basically trying to find the records that have duplicated `boxed.values`. One such example would be the first one, where `NL*2` is repeated twice.

My first idea was to project the original size of the `values` array, use `$map` to turn that array of objects into an array of strings (such as `$map: { input: "$boxed.values", in: { $concat: ["$$this.s", "*", "$$this.k"] } }`) and then remove the duplicates out of the array of strings, so i can compare the original size with the dupe-removed one. If the size would differ, then it would mean that record has duplicates.

However, it seems that there's no way in mongo (or at least I have not found one) to easily remove duplicated values out of an array of strings.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"... to easily remove duplicated values out of an array of strings."_: You can try something like in this answer using `$reduce` and `$setUnion`: [Mongo Query to fetch distinct nested documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880930/mongo-query-to-fetch-distinct-nested-documents/62987845#62987845)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$boxed.values"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "values": {
        $addToSet: "$boxed.values"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "boxed.values": "$values"
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7DOXT7USh-r). `$addToSet` is an array operation which removes duplicates

Comment: it seems that I'm also getting the version without duplicates..

Comment: The question seems tht removing duplicates of `boxed.values`